# Javascript code doesnt work in IE8/7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

This code works in chrome/ff/ie9 however not ie8/7.

http://jsfiddle.net/vDZJM/6/

Here is the JS:

```
function doDistricts(theData){
    var district="";
    var district="";
    $(theData).find("district").each(function(){

        var theDistrict = $(this);
        var districtName = theDistrict.text();
        var level = theDistrict.attr("level");
        var attr = theDistrict.attr('deleted');
        if(typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false){
            district=district+'\t\t\t<div class="district deleted">\n';
            district=district+'\t\t\t\t<header class="clearfix doNode" data-role-id="'+districtName+'" data-role-nodeLevel="'+level+'" data-role-nodeValue="'+districtName+'">\n';
            district=district+'\t\t\t\t\t<span class="arrow"></span>\n';
            district=district+'\t\t\t\t\t<img src="/img/address_list/map.png" alt="'+districtName+'" class="icon" />\n';
            district=district+'\t\t\t\t\t<span class="text">'+districtName+'</span>\n';
            district=district+'\t\t\t\t\t<a class="add" href="#">Add</a>\n';
            district=district+'\t\t\t\t</header>\n';
            district=district+'\t\t\t\t<div class="children"></div>\n';
            district=district+'\t\t\t</div>\n';
        }else{
            district=district+'\t\t\t<div class="district">\n';
            district=district+'\t\t\t\t<header class="clearfix doNode" data-role-nodeLevel="'+level+'" data-role-id="'+districtName+'" data-role-nodeValue="'+districtName+'">\n';
            district=district+'\t\t\t\t\t<span class="arrow"></span>\n';
            district=district+'\t\t\t\t\t<img src="/img/address_list/map.png" alt="'+districtName+'" class="icon" />\n';
            district=district+'\t\t\t\t\t<span class="text">'+districtName+'</span>\n';
            district=district+'\t\t\t\t\t<a class="remove" href="#">Remove</a>\n';
            district=district+'\t\t\t\t</header>\n';
            district=district+'\t\t\t\t<div class="children"></div>\n';
            district=district+'\t\t\t</div>\n';
        }

    });
    return district;
}

$('div.1').html(doDistricts($(theData)));
```

In a working environment with more code etc, the content is generated but the `<header>` tag is prematurely closed, meaning all the code that should be inside the `<header>` tag (`<span class="arrow">` etc) actually goes outside of it. Why would this be?

Comment: You don't really need to write `district=district+'...'`, you can just use `district += '...'` ;)

Comment: The `<header>` tag is an HTML5 tag that older versions of IE don't know about. You should try [the HTML5 shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/).

Comment: Sure, it's quite rushed code and needs tidying

Comment: @Pointy thats a good point as to why it wont work in jsfiddle.. stupid me.. however in live enviro I use modernizr

Comment: Ah.  Hmm.  Well that behavior is what you'd expect if the browser didn't know that `<header>` has a block content model. If (as a test) if you change `<header>` to `<div>` does it work?

Comment: And please don't add tabulations `\t` neither newline `\n` to build html

Comment: don't you hate it when it's just IE that screws your app

Comment: @Pointy, good shout - it does work.....

Comment: @DidierG. ok, Dany Khalife yes!

Comment: @Pointy - feel free to post your solution as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your document is html5 you will need to use innershiv when adding elements to the DOM

http://jdbartlett.com/innershiv/

Comment: Ok I see... this only works with innerHTML though but I will adapt my code, thanks!

Comment: Just noticed that the new version of jQuery actually does the innershiv stuff for you :)

Comment: Changing my page to load jQuery 1.7 but this had no effect :(